# javascript regex to remove particular format text from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic string and I want to remove particular format text from String. (i.e *Number)

For example: `/1*Region 1/42*Europe/51*Test/100*New Folder/119*New Folder`

Output : `/Region 1/Europe/Test/New Folder/New Folder`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your attempt

Comment: @Rory - I tried test.replace(/\d+/g, ''); It removes all numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = "/1*Region 1/42*Europe/51*Test/100*New Folder/119*New Folder";

var regex = /(\/\d+\*)/g;

var output = str.replace( regex, '/' );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @MohammedFarooq glad to know it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to search for a digit (`\d+`) followed by a * (`\*`) and replace it with nothing.

```js
var dynamic="/1*Region 1/42*Europe/51*Test/100*New Folder/119*New Folder";

var edited=dynamic.replace(/\d+\*/g, '');

console.log(edited);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `split` and `join`:

```js
var str = '/1*Region 1/42*Europe/51*Test/100*New Folder/119*New Folder',
    result = str.split(/\d+\*/).join('');   

console.log(result);
```